# How do you edit the contextual links on a custom block in drupal 8?

Tags: blocks, 8

Currently the only link that shows on the contextual links for custom blocks is the "configure block" link. I want to add an edit link to get to the main content of the block, is this possible?

Comment: Yep, definitely possible, [as shown in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133283). Which part of the docs are you struggling with exactly, or is it just that you haven't looked for them yet?

Comment: Thanks for the link Clive. Is it possible to add this for custom blocks added via the UI, currently it seems that the .yml that handles the default block lives in core... block.contextual_links.yml for example.. how would you extend this, ie something that's defined by a core module.

Comment: You've always got [`hook_contextual_links_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21contextual%21contextual.api.php/function/hook_contextual_links_view_alter/8), but I haven't tried adding stuff to custom blocks yet. Interesting question, would you mind editing the post to confirm that you're particularly interested in custom blocks? I think that point changes the question considerably